# Grommet v2 `List` raise an error when used with next.js v13 app router

Tags: next.js13, grommet

## Description

1. We are using Next.js v13 app router with Grommet v2.
2. We are using `tsx` as our file extention.
3. We are using the `List` element with children.

## Code

```
// page.tsx

'use client';

import { Grommet, Text, Box, List } from 'grommet';

export default function Page() {
  return (
    <Grommet>
      <Box>
      <List data={[ 'abc', 'def' ]} border={false}>
        {
          (datum) => (
          <Box direction='row' justify='between'>
            <Text>{datum}</Text>
          </Box>)
        }
      </List>
      </Box>
    </Grommet>
  );
}
```

## Result

Run `npm run build`:

```
./app/page.tsx:10:9
Type error: Type '(datum: any) => Element' is not assignable to type '((...args: any[]) => any) & ReactNode'.
  Type '(datum: any) => Element' is not assignable to type '((...args: any[]) => any) & string'.
    Type '(datum: any) => Element' is not assignable to type 'string'.

   8 |       <Box>
   9 |       <List data={[ 'abc', 'def' ]} border={false}>
> 10 |         {
     |         ^
  11 |           (datum) => (
  12 |           <Box direction='row' justify='between'>
  13 |             <Text>{datum}</Text>
```

## Question

How to resolve it?